# Writing to a file with map container contents c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, containers, fstream, ostream

My question is about writing to a c++ text file with contents from a map. Currently I am trying to write to my file in the current way:

```
void toFile()
{
   ofstream outFile;
   outFile.open("random.txt");
   if(outFile.is_open()){
      for(it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++){
         if(mymap.size()!=0){
            outFile << it->second.listInfo() << endl;
            outFile.close();
        }   
        else{
            cout << "An Error has occured" << endl;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

My function listInfo() is a function that just prints out information from my own implemented class.

```
void listInfo(){
cout << "NAME: " << name << "Adress " << adress << "Color " << color;
}
```

My question is when i use: `it->second.listInfo()` to write to my file I get an error but when I use `it->first` instead I don't get an error. Can somebody please explain why my code generates an error and not listing the information from my subclass to my file?

Comment: Your function returns `void`. You are trying to print `void` to a file. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: What is mymap? if(mymap.size()!=0) is useless since you for loop will iterate only if there is something in your 'mymap' (map?)

Comment: @JeromeL mymap is the name of my map container that I have implemented. Yeah thanks for that information I have been trying to code in a couple of different ways and must have stupified myself with that if-case. Thanks for your info about that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be writing to a file:

```
outFile << it->second.listInfo() << endl;

// This doesnt return anything it simply writes to standard out. 
void listInfo(){
  cout << "NAME: " << name << "Adress " << adress << "Color " << color;
}
```

You are probably looking to do something like this:

```
void YourClass::listInfo(std::ofstream ) {
    out << "NAME: " << name << "Adress " << adress << "Color " << color << endl;

}


it->second.listInfo(outFile);
```

This way your data can successfully be streamed to a file.

Comment: Cheers, thanks it successfully helped me with the code and my troubleshooting til next time! Void does not print anything out. @Ben